# How to transfer opened pages in filrefox?

Tags: firefox, sync, tabs

I have recently been forced to reinstall Ubuntu due to my ssd card problem. I had opened several pages in firefox and I want to know how it is possible to transfer those pages to newly installed Ubuntu and firefox.

Comment: Unless you were previously using a Firefox sync account there's obviously no way.

Comment: If you have a backup of your old data, you can copy the Firefox profile to the new installation. However, this won't automatically reopen the pages you had open, unless you had Firefox configured to reopen the last session on startup.

Comment: [Steps](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles#w_locate-your-profile-folder) on that _could_ restore it if like @raj says, you've got access to the backup. Profile info located in "$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/"